# AutoreleasePool in UIApplication Loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsautoreleasepool

i have an app that starts with the default code for iPhone Apps:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
```

Cause my app never stopps, the `[pool release]` is never called. Has the standard UI loop of `UIApplicationMain` an own `AutoreleasePool` which destroys the autoreleased objects of my app periodical? Or did i have to use a new `AutoreleasePool` on my own responsibility at a point of my code, which is periodical called to keep my app clean of memory leaks when it runs endless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["is the main.m really the place, where the autorelease pool of the main run loop is created by every event?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798950/is-the-main-m-really-the-place-where-the-autorelease-pool-of-the-main-run-loop-i)